# Laravel DataTable not displaying Data

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatables

I'm trying to display some data in my Laravel App but for some reason, it's not displaying properly. I'm making use of this package: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="best-sold-table-sort">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{ trans('labels.backend.table.store.best_sold.product') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('labels.backend.table.store.best_sold.revenue') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('labels.backend.table.store.best_sold.sold') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('labels.backend.table.store.best_sold.discount') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('labels.backend.table.store.best_sold.price_excl') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('labels.backend.table.store.best_sold.price_incl') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('labels.backend.table.store.best_sold.margin') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('labels.backend.table.store.best_sold.profit') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('labels.backend.table.store.best_sold.roas') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('labels.backend.table.store.best_sold.exclude_reason') }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="show-when-sibling-is-empty">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10"><em>{{ trans('strings.backend.stores.tables.no_products') }}</em></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the table that's being filled.

```
let type = 'salable';
    let channel = 'general';
    date = '1 January 2017 - 31 December 2017';
    let table = $('#best-sold-table-sort').DataTable({
        'processing': true,
        'serverSide': true,
        'ajax': '{!! route('admin.ajax.dashboard.best_sold.get') !!}/' + type + '/' + channel + '/' + date,
        'responsive': true,
        'paging': false,
        'lengthChange': false,
        'searching': false,
        'ordering': true,
        'info': false,
        'autoWidth': false,
        'columns': [
            {data: 'title', name: 'title'},
            {data: 'revenue', name: 'revenue'},
            {data: 'stock_sold', name: 'stock_sold'},
            {data: 'discount', name: 'discount'},
            {data: 'price_excl', name: 'price_excl'},
            {data: 'price_incl', name: 'price_incl'},
            {data: 'margin', name: 'margin'},
            {data: 'profit', name: 'profit'},
            {data: 'roas_target', name: 'roas_target'},
            {data: 'exclude_reason', name: 'exclude_reason'},
        ],        
});
```

This is my script.

```
public function getBestSoldData(Request $request) {
    return Datatables::of(\DB::table('aggregated_to_best_sold'))->make(true);
}
```

This is the function that's being called by the ajax route.

```
Route::get('dashboard/get/bestSoldTable/{type?}/{channel?}/{date?}', 'Ajax\DashboardController@getBestSoldData')
    ->name('dashboard.best_sold.get');
```

This is my route file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b1CF.jpg This is a part of the response that I get back through the ajax call. I checked that the JSON is valid.
I think it has something to do with the draw function of the DataTables. From what I understand it's supposed to show the amount of rows being redrawn in the table and in my json response it's either a 1 or a 0.

I hope someone will be able to help get to the bottom of this.

Comment: You should not have a `tbody` in your HTML, the DataTable will show no results message on its own.

Comment: Ah that appeared to have done the trick, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss something this ")" after (\DB::table('aggregated_to_best_sold').

try this one.

```
 public function getBestSoldData(Request $request) {
        return Datatables::of(\DB::table('aggregated_to_best_sold')
          ->make(true);
         }
```